# Logitech option mouse software does not work when software is minimized

Tags: windows, mouse, logitech-mouse

Whenever I start my (Windows) PC, Logitech Options software is started automatically.

But when I try to minimise or let it open at one of the active windows, functionality like horizontal scrolling and infinite scrolling works.

But when I close from top right hand side button, functionality mentioned above stop working after some time.

I did not able to find out the way to minimize in the Options software?
always I had to open the option from start to get additional functionalities mentioned.

Comment: I probably cannot help. I have a LogiTech mouse (several actually) this one is M535. I have the newest Options version (9.70.68) and my mouse works with Options not running.  But I use simple minded options so that is why I cannot assist